# create a raw python file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to Python. I start learning it with Jupyter notebook. It is very useful to test python code at the same time I can document what I've learned with markdown supported by Jupiter.

Until I started with module/package I noticed that every file ends with " notebook extension **.ipynb**. I understand that in order for Jupyter to have this good-looking visualization it has to store the file in some kind of format.

is there any solution to create a raw python file using Jupyter?

I am ok if I have to install other plugins to accomplish this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you created a jupyter notebook (.ipynb), and your goal is to create a python executable file (.py) from it, you can directly use the menu option from "File > Download as > Python (.py)" as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Actually jupyter allows to create plain-text file:

Create a new text file

[image: Create a Text Field]

Save the text file with python extension

[image: Save with python file extension]

Comment: There is also the option to change the Language in order to get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 13):

In order to create a python file from an existing notebook (`somenotebook.ipynb`), please run

`jupyter nbconvert somenotebook.ipynb --to script`

This will create `somenotebook.py`.

Answer (score 13):

Another way of creating a python file and executing it from within Jupyter notebook cell is as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect! Despite 8 years developing software in JS, Go, and Rust, I can't get a Python environment to work reliably on my machine, so I'm just doing everything on FloydHub 

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find such option in jupyter notebook, but you can create empty *.py file and then open with jupyter. It is better then plain text, because you get colored  text.

Comment: Python file is a plain text with extension .py.

Comment: FYI: source code is a plain text and a Python file is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach of adding code from jupyter notebook cells to a `.py` is by using the built-in Magic command **%logstart**.

The `%writefile` saves the current cell code to a `.py` file.

**%logstart**

From the [Documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

Start logging anywhere in a session.

`%logstart [-o|-r|-t|-q] [log_name [log_mode]]`

If no name is given, it defaults to a file named `ipython_log.py` in your current directory, in `rotate` mode (see below).

`%logstart name` saves to file `name` in `backup` mode. It saves your history up to that point and then continues logging.

`%logstart` takes a second optional parameter: `logging mode`. This can be one of (note that the modes are given unquoted):

```
append
Keep logging at the end of any existing file.

backup
Rename any existing file to name~ and start name.

global
Append to a single logfile in your home directory.

over
Overwrite any existing log.

rotate
Create rotating logs: name.1~, name.2~, etc.
```

Check more options in the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

Example:

```
%logstop
%logstart -ort sample.py append
```

The above command appends all the Jupyter notebook code to sample.py

Note: Should run in the first cell

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got a ipynb as a .py script file:

Goto  File-> Save And Export Notebook As ->Executable Script
.py file will be downloaded to Downloads folder.
I run Version 4.0.0 of Jupyterlab in a chromebrowser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnObN.png)

You need to select all cells in the notebook to save all the contents into .py file

Comment: And if you want to do it conveniently on the command line, [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html) is a nice tool in the current Jupyter ecosystem that's perhaps a bit easier with more features than `jupyter nbconvert`.